# Unable to run cmd.exe by using ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, json, cmd

Web.config:

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="MystemDirectory" value="D:\mystem\"/>
</appSettings>
```

Controller:

```
if (flag)
{
    db.FbDocuments.Add(fbDocument);
    db.SaveChanges();

    var workingDirectory = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MystemDirectory"];
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(workingDirectory + @"\input.txt", fbDocument.Title);
    Process process = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    processStartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
    processStartInfo.Arguments = "mystem.exe --format json input.txt output.txt";
    process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
    process.Start();
    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(workingDirectory + @"\output.txt");
    var jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var jsonCleanText = jsSerializer.Deserialize<CleanText>(text);

    var fbToUpdate = db.FbDocuments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == fbDocument.Id);
    fbToUpdate.CleanText = jsonCleanText.ToString();
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

When the code in the controller writes the text in input.txt, but output.txt remains empty. If run cmd.exe manually, everything works... After the files input.txt output.txt and remain filled, and if you run the code in the controller again, an error in the variable jsonCleanText invalid format JSON and output.txt value does not change.

Comment: If you're running an exe anyway, why are you launching a shell to run it instead of doing process.Start on mystem directly?

Comment: how to run directly?

Comment: You don't need to call `cmd.exe` to run your process. Just directly use `mystem.exe` for the `processStartInfo.FileName`. And remove the program name from your arguments.

Comment: Worked! Thanks, 
how about invalid format JSON???

Comment: Invalid format JSON in var jsonCleanText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
            if (flag)
                    {
                        db.FbDocuments.Add(fbDocument);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        var workingDirectory = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MystemDirectory"];
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(workingDirectory + @"\input.txt", fbDocument.Title);
                        Process process = new Process();
                        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                        processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                        processStartInfo.FileName = "mystem.exe";
                        processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
                        processStartInfo.Arguments = "--format json input.txt output.txt";
                        process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
                        process.Start();
                        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(workingDirectory + @"\output.txt");
                        var jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                        var jsonCleanText = jsSerializer.Deserialize<CleanText>(text);

                        var fbToUpdate = db.FbDocuments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == fbDocument.Id);
                        fbToUpdate.CleanText = jsonCleanText.ToString();
                        db.SaveChanges();

                    }
```